# Apache CXF catch SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, exception, cxf

I have `CXF service` and set time out to this:

```
@Bean(name = "MyPortType")
public MyPortType myPortType() {
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(MyPortType .class);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(myUrl);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new FaultOutInterceptor());
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new FaultOutInterceptor());
    MyPortType myPortType = (MyPortType ) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(signingPortType);
    configClient(client, 60000L, 30000L);

    return myPortType ;
}

private void configClient(Client client, long connectionTimeout, long receiveTimeout) {
    if (client != null) {
        HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        policy.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        policy.setReceiveTimeout(receiveTimeout);
        conduit.setClient(policy);
    }
}
```

I set connection timeout and receive timeout. And noe I try use this service in my code:

```
     try {
        //create request
        myPortType.sendRequest(myRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

How can I catch TimeOutException?

if I try next:

```
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
          log.error(ex .getMessage(), ex );
        }
        else if (ex instanceof ConnectException) {
            log.error(ex .getMessage(), ex );
        }

    }
```

Intellij IDE say:

```
Condition 'ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException' is always 'false' less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

**EDIT**

[image]

```
public byte[] sign(SigningRequestType request) throws SigningFaultMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
catch(SocketTimeoutException ex) {
log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex ); //TODO specific thing if socket time out
} catch(ConnectException ex) {
log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex ); //TODO specific thing if connect expcetion happened
}catch (Exception ex) {
log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex );   //TODO specific thing if generic exception happened
}
```

If the code throw `SocketTimeoutException` it will catch from first block.

Comment: I edit my questions. I do not like the fact that the environment highlights it and gives messages

Comment: basically you want to catch SocketTimeoutException.isn't it?

Comment: yes, I want catch exception and separate it. Ihave error messages in DB and depending on what error I caught I will form an internal message. SocketTimeoutException and ConnectException  - has different messages in my DB and other exceptions has other text message in DB

Comment: That message should be available in `ex` exception object. ex.getMessage() etc. If your method throw an exception of type SocketTimeoutException or ConnectException, it should catch in the relevant exception block.